# Problem with QIBASE (firebird + Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, firebird, qtsql

Good morning.

I've tried to compile QIBASE driver to access FireBird database using sqlbrowser from %QTDIR/demos. But after i filled all fields in sqlbrowser and pushed OK button the program crashed with message:

```
/opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.3/demos/sqlbrowser-build-desktop/sqlbrowser: symbol lookup error: 
/usr/lib/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlibase.so: undefined symbol: isc_attach_database
```

To compile QIBASE driver i've done following steps:

1. Installing FirebirdCS-2.5.0 to /opt/firebird.
2. Unzipping qt sources to /opt/qt4.
3. Compiling QIBASE driver:

   cd /opt/qt/src/plugins/sqldrivers/ibase
   qmake -o Makefile "INCLUDEPATH+=/opt/firebird/include" "LIBS+=-     L/opt/firebird/lib/libfbclient.so" ibase.pro
4. Put libqsqlibase.so to /usr/lib/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers
5. Fill all fields in sqlbrowser, push OK and propgram crashed with above-mentioned message.

The database is OK: i've connected to it and executed queries by isql.

Help me please to solve the problem.
Thank you.

Ubuntu 10.10, Qt4, firebird 2.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
The problem was that i compiled sqlbrowser with qt4.7.0 installed from binaries, but QIBASE driver was compiled with qt4.7.3.