# Qt 5.x. compiling IBASE plagin Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: qt, ubuntu, firebird

I have a problem, you need to assemble the ibase plugin in qt5 in ubuntu. After a series of manipulations carried out by me I. I assume that you need to mount the folder include/firebird but can't find her.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.6 /usr/lib/libfbclient.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.6 /usr/lib/libgds.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libfbclient.so /usr/lib/libgds.so.0
sudo ln /usr/lib/libfbclient.so /usr/lib/lgds.so
sudo ln /usr/lib/libfbclient.so /usr/lib/libgds.so
```

Installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep firebird
firebird-dev                    install
firebird2.5-classic             deinstall
firebird2.5-common              install
firebird2.5-common-doc              install
firebird2.5-server-common           install
firebird2.5-super               install
libreoffice-sdbc-firebird           install

gbak -z
gbak:gbak version LI-V2.5.6.27020 Firebird 2.5

dpkg -L firebird2.5-super
/.
/etc
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/firebird2.5-super
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/fbstat
/usr/bin/fbsvcmgr
/usr/bin/fbtracemgr
/usr/bin/gbak
/usr/bin/gdef
/usr/bin/gfix
/usr/bin/gpre
/usr/bin/gsec
/usr/bin/isql-fb
/usr/bin/nbackup
/usr/bin/qli
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/firebird
/usr/lib/firebird/2.5
/usr/lib/firebird/2.5/UDF
/usr/lib/firebird/2.5/UDF/fbudf.so
/usr/lib/firebird/2.5/UDF/ib_udf.so
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/fb_lock_print
/usr/sbin/fbserver
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/firebird2.5-super
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/fbserver.1.gz
/usr/share/doc/firebird2.5-super
```

Building:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/firebird/2.5/firebird.msg /opt/firebird/firebird.msg

sudo nano /etc/profile
export FIREBIRD="/opt/firebird"

qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/bin/" "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so" "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/lgds.so" "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so" "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/libgds.so" "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/firebird/2.5/" "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib64 -lfbclient" ibase.pro


make
```

[log for Qt 5.2.1 - 5.3](http://sitefresh.net/pages/error-log-n4-ibase-qt.html)

[log for Qt 5.4-5.5](http://sitefresh.net/pages/error-log-n3-ibase-qt.html)

[log for Qt 5.6](http://sitefresh.net/pages/error-log-n1-ibase-qt.html)

[log for Qt 5.7](http://sitefresh.net/pages/error-log-n2-ibase-qt.html)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993143/problem-with-qibase-firebird-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: Looks like you are missing ibase.h

Comment: @MarkRotteveel locate ibase.h
/usr/include/ibase.h
/usr/include/qt4/Qt/qsql_ibase.h
/usr/include/qt4/QtSql/qsql_ibase.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was successfully compiled on Ubuntu 16.10 and Debian jessie.

Preamble:

- on Debian was used `su -` instead `sudo`
- for building of the QT sources used
  [wiki](http://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git)
- `/etc/apt/source.list` - you must put some source URI's `deb-src ...` here

Install the packages:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep qt5-default
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0-dev
sudo apt-get install firebird-dev
```

The source tree was cloned from git repository:

```
cd /usr/src # or any directory you want with w+x 
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git

cd qt5;
git checkout 5.7

perl init-repository

./configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

The configure found nothing in the step above to build InterBase plugin:

```
  SQL drivers:
    DB2 .................. no
    InterBase ............ no
    MySQL ................ yes (plugin)
    OCI .................. no
    ODBC ................. yes (plugin)
    PostgreSQL ........... yes (plugin)
    SQLite 2 ............. no
    SQLite ............... yes (plugin, using bundled copy)
    TDS .................. yes (plugin)

make -j4

# make install # it isn't needed because developers-build
```

For building `firebird` plugin was used [this doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qibase)

```
export QTDIR=/usr/src/qt5
export PATH=$QTDIR/qtbase/bin:$PATH

cd $QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/ibase

# to avoid linker error: /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lgds
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so /usr/lib/libgds.so

qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lfbclient" ibase.pro
make
```

I experienced following bug on Ubuntu only [bug-report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53375)

> /usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:75:25: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file
>   or directory
>        #include_next 
>                                ^

Generated Makefile should be modified in the following way:

```
INCPATH       = -I. -isystem /usr/include
--> new
INCPATH       = -I. -I/usr/include
```

Afterwords, re-execute `make`:

```
rm -f libqsqlibase.so
g++ -Wl,--no-undefined -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/src/qt5/qtbase/lib -shared -o libqsqlibase.so .obj/main.o .obj/qsql_ibase.o .obj/moc_qsql_ibase_p.o  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lfbclient -lgds -L/usr/src/qt5/qtbase/lib -lQt5Sql -lQt5Core -lpthread
mv -f libqsqlibase.so ../../../../plugins/sqldrivers/

-rwxr-xr-x 1 db src 1241008 May  1 23:55 ../../../../plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlibase.so
```

That's all. The simplest test program shows that ibase plugin is available now:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "drivers available:" << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
    QCoreApplication::exit(0);
}
```

> drivers available: ("QIBASE", "QSQLITE", "QMYSQL", "QMYSQL3", "QODBC", "QODBC3", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7", "QTDS", "QTDS7")

I hope this will help you.